# Parsing the recursive Hanoi Tower algorithm

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

I am sorry to ask this question, but I didn't find any of the other existing threads useful. I have to say I have a difficulty wrapping my head around complex topics, maybe I am just dumb. I am deeply sorry for that. Anyway, I tried to parse the following, but there's something amiss.

```
   public class tower {
  public static void move(int n, int startPole, int endPole) {
    if (n== 0){
      return;
    }
    int intermediatePole = 6 - startPole - endPole;
    move(n-1, startPole, intermediatePole);
    System.out.println("Move " +n + " from " + startPole + " to " +endPole);
    move(n-1, intermediatePole, endPole);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    move(2, 1, 3);
  }
}
```

I scribbled some notes to help myself parse the code:

```
move(2,1,3)
move(1,1,2)
n==0

--------going back up

n==0
move(1,1,2)
Move 1 from 1 to 2
move(2,1,3)
Move 2 from 1 to 3

move(2,1,3)
move(1,2,3)
n==0

-------going back up

n==0
move(1,2,3)
Move 1 from 2 to 3
move(2,1,3)
?????????? (step is missing)
```

The second recursion call stops prematurely and I wanted to know what I have overlooked.

I found the iterative code to be much easier to understand and I wrote a recursive algorithm based on the iterative algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
move(2,1,3)
+--move(1,1,2)
|  +--move(0,1,3)
|  |  '--(do nothing)
|  +--print "move from 1 to 2"
|  '--move(0,3,2)
|     '--(do nothing)
+--print "move from 1 to 3"
'--move(1,2,3)
   +--move(0,2,1)
   |  '--(do nothing)
   +--print "move from 2 to 3"
   '--move(0,1,3)
      '--(do nothing)
```

To move *n* discs from tower *a* to tower *b*, you need to

1. Move the top *n* - 1 discs out of the way, using tower *c*.
2. Move the bottom disc to tower *b*.
3. Move the top back on top of the previous disc, on tower *b*.

Step 1 and 3 are done recursively.

---

```java
/** Moves n discs from startPole to endPole */
public static void move(int n, int startPole, int endPole) {
    if (n == 0) {
        // Base case: No disk to move. Do nothing.
        return;
    }

    // Calculate the pole that is not startPole and not endPole.
    // 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
    // 6 - 1 - 2 = 3
    // 6 - 1 - 3 = 2
    // 6 - 2 - 3 = 1
    int intermediatePole = 6 - startPole - endPole;

    // Step 1: Move n-1 discs out of the way, to the intermediate pole.
    move(n-1, startPole, intermediatePole);

    // Step 2: Move the bottom disc to the destination, the end pole.
    System.out.println("Move " + n + " from " + startPole + " to " + endPole);

    // Step 3: Move the n-1 discs back on top of the previous disc, on the end pole.
    move(n-1, intermediatePole, endPole);
}
```

Comment: oh yeah this is my mistake: move(2,1,3). I can parse it now, but I don't understand EXACTLY why it works, so I can't code it without remembering the code pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether your note is correct,its looks confused.

When your code executes, it runs like this:

> > move(2,1,3)

turns to

> > move(1,1,2)
> >
> > (output)"Move 2 from 1 to 3"
> >
> > move(1,2,3)

while

> > move(1,1,2)

turns to

> > move(0,1,3) // do nothing
> >
> > (output)"Move 1 from 1 to 2"
> >
> > move(0,3,2) //do nothing

and

> > move(1,2,3)

turns to

> > move(0,2,1) // do nothing
> >
> > (output)"Move 1 from 2 to 3"
> >
> > move(0,1,3) // do nothing

so its output:

> > "Move 1 from 1 to 2"
> >
> > "Move 2 from 1 to 3"
> >
> > "Move 1 from 2 to 3"

The puzzling thing may be the n in the output.It does matter in its move(),and just describles the sum of elements which will be move in this move(n-1,...,...), move(n,...,...) and next move(n-1,...,...),not only a move(n,...,...) .